# jQuery Plugin to limit styles to a specifc area

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, scope, styles

I'm searching for something that applies styles only to a specific area:

```
<div class="showcase limited-styles">
    <style scoped type="text/css">/* some styles */</style>
    <!-- the actual content - only affected by the style definitions above -->
</div>
```

I [already found jQuery Scoped](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin), but for some reason it doesn't work for me - all the other styles apply as well, so it's not any better as using the highest available specifity.

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't jQuery Scoped work for you? What problems were you facing with it?

Comment: It can't lock out other style definitions, or jump in with higher specifity.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Btw: I already mentioned that in the Q :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could accomplish this by "parenting"

Throw a containing div around all of the elements you want to respond independently, and then put that div name in front of other DOM elements you are trying to style.

```
Here is a fiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/3mx4L07t/
```

Comment: This is basic CSS. Please read my question again: It's about locking other styles out completely.